# Is it possible to fix `Image failed to verify with *ACCESS DENIED*` error without access to BIOS?

Tags: boot, permissions, uefi

## Preliminaries

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. And now I want to change to other distro. However, after trying to boot from USB (with Arch iso) I had the error

> Image failed to verify with *ACCESS DENIED*

The important thing is that *I have no access to BIOS* because I don't remember the password. So I cannot enable the Legacy mode. (I disabled Secure Mode with MOK utils but no success).

## Problem

After numerous tries to boot from USB I (desparately) ran the command

```
apt install grub-efi-amd64
```

After that the above error occurs not only when I try to boot from USB, but also when I try to boot from my SSD. Now I cannot boot at all.

How to deal with that situation? I am not even interested in saving the data on the SSD. The main goal is to be able to boot my machine.

Thanks in advance.